# How much antimatter could a 100-Petawatt laser produce in outer space?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass-energy, estimation, antimatter

How much antimatter could a 100-Petawatt laser theoretically produce during (for example) 30 femtoseconds?

The laser would produce electron-positron pairs using the mechanism outlined in this article from LaserFocusWorld: [Laser pulses make electrons produce gamma rays, then matter/antimatter pairs of particles](https://www.laserfocusworld.com/test-measurement/research/article/16571409)

> An optical trap for matter-antimatter plasma is formed by four laser beams arranged in one plane, all heading towards the same point. When the lasers overlap they form a 2D wave, with electric fields shown in the figure. A nanowire object is placed in the center; the electrons are stripped off the wire and accelerated close to the speed of light.
>
> They are trapped in the wave, so when they lose most of their energy by emitting light, they get reaccelerated. The photons produce electron-positron pairs, themselves trapped. This process can create a dense electron-positron plasma that eventually converts most of the available laser energy into gamma-rays.

Comment: What would the answer to this question teach you about understanding physics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $E=mc^2$

$m = 3000 Petafemtojoules / c^2 = 3000 joules / c^2$

Since the joule is a SI unit, we need $c$ in m/s to get mass in kg:

$m = 3000 / (3 \times 10^8)^2 = 3.3 \times 10^{-14}$

which is $3.3 \times10^{-11}$ grams.

As G. Smith points out, only half of this will be antimatter.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(mass)#10%E2%88%9218_to_10%E2%88%9213_kg

Comment: The arithmetic may be fine, but there is no way electromagnetic light energy can turn into matter antimatter, **unless the individual photons/γ  interact with a field** . see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production#Cross_section

Comment: @KeithMcClary Thanks for your answer. With this calculator: https://www.anycalculator.com/antimatterenergy.html I get 2965883 joules, which then gives me 9.8862766667e+19 watts per pulse. Is this right? Seems too high.

Comment: @user287933 For .000000000000033 kg it gives 5931.766055423999 Joules. (My answer was rounded from 3.33333333333... .)

Comment: @user287933 "watts per pulse" No, watts is energy/time. You want energy per pulse.

Comment: @annav That should also be an answer.

Comment: @KeithMcClary Thanks for the clarification. I therefore assume that this calculator https://www.anycalculator.com/antimatterenergy.html is wrong.

Comment: No, I put in  .000000000000033 kg and it  gave 5931.766055423999 Joules. The difference from 6000 is due to my round-off.

Comment: @user287933 Although, as G. Smith pointed out, you would need an equal amount of matter to release the energy, and then you would get twice as much energy.

Comment: @Keith McClary thanks for the clarification, btw lastly, how can I 'introduce' in the equation the power output of the electron gun? i assume the amount of antimatter created does not only depend on the power of laser, but also on the power of the electron gun and therefore the number of electrons available for laser collision.

Answer (score 2):

Please keep in mind that the arithmetic in the answer of *Keith McClary* may be fine, but the energy in an electromagnetic wave cannot magically be transformed to antiparticles.

Antparticles are quantum mechanical entities, and in order to produce them, the individual photons/γ which make up the electromagnetic wave have to [interact with a field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production#Cross_section) in order to produce a pair of particle-antiparticle,

[image]

The energy of the individual photon has to be at least the summed mass of the two particle antiparticles, so this petawat laser will have to be in *gamma ray frequencies,* to be able to create a pair of electron positrons.

> [For example](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/29-3-photon-energies-and-the-electromagnetic-spectrum/), a γ-ray photon with f = 1021 Hz has an energy $E = hf = 6.63 × 10^{−13}$ J = 4.14 MeV.

So it is not enough to talk about peta-energies for lasers, the frequency is important in antimatter production, and there are no gamma ray lasers.

[There is ongoing research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma-ray_laser) to create gamma ray lasers, not successful up to now.

> A gamma-ray laser, or graser, is a hypothetical device that would produce coherent gamma rays, just as an ordinary laser produces coherent rays of visible light

Edit [after search for pair particle](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=laser%20virtual%20photons%20pair%20creation) creation in lasers, where a number of entries came, with virtual photons produced using laser beams.

> [Generation of high-energy electron-positron pairs in the collision of a laser-accelerated electron beam with a multipetawatt laser

> Generation of electron-positron pairs via the multiphoton Breit-Wheeler process in an all-optical scheme will be made possible on forthcoming high-power laser facilities through the collision of wakefield-accelerated GeV electrons with a counter-propagating laser pulse of $10^{22}–10^{23}$W $cm{−2}$ peak intensity. of a laser-accelerated electron beam with a multipetawatt laser

> 

The point still exists though, that only some of the energy of a laser beam can be used to create particle antiparticle pairs, interacting with some other fields.

Comment: The OP attempted to ask about this on Astronomy SE. Fortunately, they posted a link to an article about the specific antimatter generation process they have in mind. So I've updated this question to include that link, and a brief summary of the article. It seems like a very interesting process. But as you say, only a small proportion of the laser energy can actually get converted into particles.